# No changes in database when use raw SQL

Tags: python, sql, django

I need to write to database many simple records and using orm method for it is very slow, so I've decided to try raw SQL. I've wrote code, here it is:

```
for row in rows:
    name = row.split('\t')[0].lower()
    print name
    try:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO domain_browser_domain (name) VALUES (%s)", [name])
    except django.db.utils.IntegrityError:
        continue
```

The problem is... it actually doesn't write anything to database. Field `name` is defined as unique so when the `execute` method is not in `try` block it returns `IntegrityError` because there are already some records in database.

Comment: Which DBMS? In some you have to explicitly commit

Comment: So what db errors you get?

Comment: I don't get any python exceptions. I use SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have answered your own question. You're not able to insert the new row into the database because it violates an integrity constraint *within the database itself*. This is not an instance of Django stopping you from doing something. Rather, Django is interpreting the error returned from the database.

Comment: There are also a lot of data that actually is not in the table, but they weren't written to DB too...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add commas after each value in the `name` variable. As your query is constructed now it will end up looking like this:

`INSERT INTO domain_browser_domain (name) VALUES (one two three)` without the commas.

You need to format your query before executing it.

What is the output of the print statement?

Answer (score 0):

Use `transaction.commit_unless_managed()` after the `cursor.execute()`. Everything worked but it's performance was still very bad. I've read somewhere that it is because SQLite opens file everytime you execute code and right after it just closes file. So if you really need to speed up operations execution - just use `bulk_create()` method, it's described in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create).